# What SQL index should I add for this SELECT TOP 1 ... ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC query

Tags: sql, sql-server

My project has a pattern of inserting a new row into MS SQL Server for every user submission to preserve historical data. We then SELECT the most recent row for a given couple of parameters. Here is an example table:

```
CREATE TABLE dlr.[FakeSubmission] (
        [FakeSubmissionId] BIGINT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1), 
        [BusinessId] BIGINT NOT NULL, 
        [ModelId] BIGINT NOT NULL, 
        [SomeData] VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL, 
        [Price] MONEY NULL, 
        [CreatedDate] DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE(), 
        [CreatedUser] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
        CONSTRAINT [PK_FakeSubmission] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([FakeSubmissionId])
)
```

Here is some example data:

```
FakeSubmissionId    BusinessId  ModelId SomeData    Price   CreatedDate CreatedUser
1   4001    20001   data    100.00  2015-03-30 16:17:37.920 bob
2   4001    20002   data    100.00  2015-03-30 16:18:01.597 bob
3   4001    20003   data    100.00  2015-03-30 16:18:09.040 bob
4   4001    20004   data    100.00  2015-03-30 16:18:14.533 bob
5   4002    20001   data    200.00  2015-03-30 16:18:35.523 martin
6   4002    20002   data    200.00  2015-03-30 16:18:40.597 martin
7   4002    20003   data    200.00  2015-03-30 16:18:45.257 martin
8   4001    20002   data    200.00  2015-03-30 16:20:36.843 wally
9   4001    20003   data    200.00  2015-03-30 17:01:41.907 wally
```

Here is an example query:

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM
    dlr.[FakeSubmission]
WHERE
    BusinessId = 4001 AND ModelId = 20002
ORDER BY
    CreatedDate desc
```

Which returns:

```
FakeSubmissionId    BusinessId  ModelId SomeData    Price   CreatedDate CreatedUser
8   4001    20002   data    200.00  2015-03-30 16:20:36.843 wally
```

We query by selecting the `TOP 1` row ordered by `CreatedDate` given the 2 IDs, `BusinessId` and `ModelId`.

What index should I add to optimize for this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a single index that covers all three columns
BusinessID,ModelID,CreatedDate

The first two to quickly locate the record you are after (index seek), and the created date will have your data already sorted so no sort will be needed run upon select.

Answer (score 0):

I would create an compound index based on FakeSubmissionId  and  BusinessId.